# EF core 3.1 can not translate linq query

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF core 3.1 and I have an Order entity that I want to get report by this code:

```
 public async Task<List<OrderReport>> GetOrderReportAsync(DateTimeOffset @from, DateTimeOffset to,
        OrderStatus? status, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var query = _dbContext.Orders.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.StartAt >= from && x.StartAt <= to);

        if (status.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(x => x.Status == status);

        return await query
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.StartAt,
                x.Status,
                TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt64(x.TotalPrice),
                PayedPrice = Convert.ToInt64(x.PayedPrice),
            })
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.Status,
                x.StartAt.Date
            })
            .Select(x => new OrderReport()
            {
                DateTime = x.Key.Date,
                Timestamp = x.Key.Date.Ticks,
                Total = x.Count(),
                TotalPrice = x.Sum(s => s.TotalPrice),
                TotalPayedPrice = x.Sum(s => s.PayedPrice),
                Status = x.Key.Status
            }).ToListAsync(token);
    }
```

but in runtime EF throws an exception:

> The LINQ expression '(ProjectionBindingExpression: 1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

I know what the exception says but don't want to get all records in memory and then set group by - I ran the same code on EF 2.1 before and worked with no exception.

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: Have you tried narrowing the problem down by removing things from the projections (i.e., the items within the `Select` calls) one by one?

Comment: What does the constructor for `OrderReport` do?

Comment: I found the problem! because PayedPrice property is ``int?`` and I fix it by using ``PayedPrice = Convert.ToInt64(x.PayedPrice ?? 0)``

Comment: Fix that `from` typo in your query, then see what EF says.